# Matlab and MySQl, inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am having a problem loading data from MySQL into Matlab.

I am just running a stored procedure.  When I run it from MySQL it returns 1,500 rows.

When I run it from Matlab, it will return 1 record when I first start up Matlab.  If I re-run it a few times I might eventually get 1,500 rows.  Earlier it took 30 minutes before it would return 1,500 rows.

My store procedure is:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `latest_hl_tradables`()
BEGIN

DECLARE latest_date DATE ;

SELECT max(available_on_platform.on_date)
FROM available_on_platform 
INNER JOIN platform ON (available_on_platform.platform_id=platform.id)
where platform.name='aaa'
INTO latest_date;



SELECT fund_id,fund_class_id,fund_class.name as fund_class_name,sedol,isin,max(on_date) as on_date
FROM available_on_platform
INNER JOIN fund_class ON (fund_class.id=available_on_platform.fund_class_id)
INNER JOIN platform ON (available_on_platform.platform_id=platform.id)

WHERE on_date>=latest_date-5
AND platform.name='aaa'

GROUP BY fund_class_id,fund_class.name,sedol,isin;

END
```

My Matlab Code is:

```
conn=database('fund_data3','','');
sql = 'call latest_hl_tradables()';
curs = exec(conn,sql);   
curs = fetch(curs);
```

Comment: If it runs correctly from MySQL, then this would seem to be a connection to MatLab issue, or perhaps an issue with how you are reading the results there.  It would not seem to be a database issue.

Comment: Why is this a sproc anyway?